# Recursive call in Java methods allowed?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am really confused by this piece of Java code (a class called Message). I think the second constructor is set to initialize `data_length` with a value, and for this purpose it calls a method named `init` as you can see.

But what is going on inside `init` is what makes me bash my head on my desk :D What is happening inside this method? Why it is calling itself??

```
  /**
   * The actual length of the message data. Must be less than or equal to
   * (data.length - base_offset).
   */
  protected int data_length;


  /** Limit no-arg instantiation. */
  protected Message() {
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new message of the given size.
   * 
   * @param data_length
   *          The size of the message to create.
   */
  public Message(int data_length) {
    init(data_length);
  }

  public void init(int data_length) {
    init(new byte[data_length]);
  }
```

I am converting this code to C#, is it fine if I do just:

```
public class Message
{    
     //blah blah and more blah

     private int _dataLength;

     public Message(int dataLength)
     {
         _dataLength = dataLength;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It _isn't_ recursive. It is _overloaded_ I don't know where a `init(byte[] buffer)` is defined though - you didn't post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void init(int data_length) {
    init(new byte[data_length]);
}
```

It is not calling itself; it's calling another method named `init` that takes a `byte[]` as a parameter.

The class `Message` or one of its superclasses contains that other `init` method - you didn't show it to us.

Creating different methods with the same name but different parameter types is called [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 7):

It isn't calling itself.  If you look here:

```
init(new byte[data_length]);
```

The code is actually constructing a new `byte[]`, which is then used in the invocation another `init` method.  Java allows method overloading, so not all `init` methods are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is allowed in Java, but in your example `init()` isn't calling itself but another `init()` method which takes a byte array as its argument (which you didn't include in the code you posted).